# ViewPager Drag and Drop Option doesn't show up in Graphical Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml, android-library

**Problem**:
[Edit] I've got the android-support-v4.jar in the libs file.

When I edit XML's in Eclipse, it doesn't show up on the Graphical Layout screen.
Also when I hit ctrl+space to access the objects it's not in the dropdown.

**Question**: Is there any way of importing the android.support.v4 library into this list?

Answer (score 1):

All object that`s on left list , You can press on small arrow on the top left of Palette list and change it to "Show only icon and text"

That`s easy to find any object

Comment: The ViewPager is not available on that either.